# Why facebook doesn't switch my app to live mode?

Tags: live, review

Something goes wrong when I try to switch my app to live mode. There appears a dialog with a busy indicator and after about 10 seconds it disappears without any error but my app stays in development mode.

[image]

If it may be useful for you I attach javascript console I can see there is some error after the dialog is closed
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it was a sort of malfunction in facebook. I couldn't get it work for two days and right after I posted this question facebook successfully processed my "switch to live" request.
The question may be closed or... it may be left for somebody who gets to the same situation.